# Jquery on click not working when focus is in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a suggestion box below a search box. I want it so that when the user has focus in the search box, and then clicks on one of the suggestions, it triggers an action. I have tried using jquery's `on`:

```
$(".searchbox + div").on("click", "a", function() {
  $(".searchbox").val($(this).html());
});
```

My HTML structure is like this:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="searchbox">
<div></div>
```

The links are dynamically inserted inside the `div` that follows the input.
The links do not have an `href` value, so they are not really links, I just want them to act like links.

When I click on one of the links, the searchbox loses focus, and, because of the css I have, the links get `visibility:hidden`. I think the searchbox loses focus before the link action is triggered, so it never is triggered. How could I get around this?

You can see it [here](https://calebeby.github.io/WordFinder/).

Clarification: What I think is happening:

1. User clicks on link
2. Computer thinks, *The user just clicked outside of the search box*
3. Search box becomes blurred
4. CSS sees that search box is blurred, styles say to now make the suggestions `visibility:hidden`
5. Now the links are no longer clickable, so the event is never triggered.

Comment: When I search for a term and click on suggestions, the results are coming as expected. I am unsure what is not working in that page?

Comment: Try clicking on one of the suggestions, one that is different from the current query

Comment: Working fine for me - Went here first https://calebeby.github.io/WordFinder/#google , Then selected one each in sidebars and bottom... all working as intended for me

Comment: I am talking about the suggestions in the search box, if you start typing, not the rest of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you have a click handler that brings the search bar to the top and the rest of the UI into view. It executes when the user clicks anywhere that's not the search bar. You should add a statement that checks if the clicked element was an `<a>` element in the suggestion box.

So if this is the click handler. Also i think it's time to add an `id` to your suggestion div.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if($clicked.tagName == 'A' && $clicked.closest('#suggestionDivId').length>0)
        $(".searchbox").val($(this).html());
    else if(click was outside searchbar)
        //move searchbar up and show UI
    else
        //click happened inside searchbar, do nothing.
})
```

I'm not sure why nobody understands your question, or why this question is being downvoted. It's a perfectly valid question.

EDIT:

I suggest wrapping the input and suggestion div with another div. Give this wrapper an attribute of `tabindex="-1"` so it can receive blur/focus events.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="searchbox">
<div></div>
</div>
```

Then change your `$(".searchbox").on("blur")` to `$("#wrapper").on("blur")`

This way you can click anywhere in the suggestion box without the blur firing.

Alternatively, the `mousedown` event fires before the `blur` event. So try this maybe

```
$(".searchbox + div").on("mousedown", "a", function() {
  $(".searchbox").val($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: I have `$(".searchbox").on("blur")` for the content. The suggestions going away is all triggered through css, though. How would I make the link trigger even if the search box is blurred first?

Comment: I went with the `mousedown`, and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some plugins for that. Its too easy. For example if you work with any front framework like bootstrap, you can use **typeahead.js** plugin

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without a plugin?

Comment: yes. You can use without plugins. But u have to work with ajax. Only jquery is not enough to do auto complete search bar.

Comment: I think you are not understanding my question. I already have the suggestions coming up, but what doesn't work is when I am clicking on them. [demo](https://calebeby.github.io/WordFinder/)